# How to convert date string to ISO8601 standard?

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil

using dateutil I was able to genrate ISO8601 of type 
`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD` but I want the format `'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssTZD'` eg `'2015-05-13T18:05:55.320-07:00'`

My code is

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import *
from dateutil.tz import *
import dateutil
import time

ts = time.time()
utc_offset = (datetime.fromtimestamp(ts) -
           datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)).total_seconds()

now = parse("11/10/09 11:20 PM")
now = now.replace(tzinfo=tzoffset('PDT', utc_offset))
```

and output is `2009-11-10T23:20:00-07:00`
how would I get output like `2009-11-10T23:20:00.000-07:00`

Comment: unrelated: use `pytz` for a proper timezone support: `now = tzlocal.get_localzone().localize(datetime.strptime('11/10/09 11:20 PM', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M %p'), is_dst=None)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat):

```
>>> now = datetime.now(tzoffset('EDT', -4*60*60))
>>> print(now.isoformat())
2015-05-15T07:08:34.478784-04:00
```

Note that the `isoformat` method omits microseconds if the value is 0 (as in your example parsed time.  If you must have factional seconds in your output use `%f` in a format string:

```
>>> print(now.strftime("%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"))
15-05-15T07:35:00.000000-0400
```

If you need *milli*seconds, you'll have to write your own formatting routine:

```
def format_time_with_milliseconds(time):
    fmt = "{time.year:04}-{time.month:02}-{time.day:02}T{time.hour:02}:{time.minute:02}:{time.second:02}.{millisecond:03}{tz}"
    return fmt.format(time=time, millisecond=int(round(time.microsecond/1000)), tz=time.strftime("%z"))
```

Comment: I'm using isoformat to print the string, but problem is for the string format which I'm parsing I'm not able to get the microseconds

Comment: @SachinDoiphode perhaps you should edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: Nice! I think you need millisecond=int(round(now.microsecond/1000.0)) to do the rounding properly and get an integer number of millis

Comment: `/1000` works like `//1000` in Python 2 (you don't want it if you call `round()` afterwards). To get rounded milliseconds as a string: `'%03d' % (round(microseconds, -3) // 10**3)`. Also, `%z` does not include `:` (colon).

Comment: I think you meant to use `%Y` in your second snippet.

Answer (score 6):

Python's [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) method can print microseconds:

```
ISO_FORMAT_MICROS = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"
now.strftime(ISO_FORMAT_MICROS)
```

returns

```
'2009-11-10T23:20:00.000000-0700'
```

### Rounding to microseconds

The milliseconds part is a little tricky. The following code is a refinement of [RoadieRich's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30266603/199166):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def datetime_to_iso(dt):
    fmt = "{time.year:04}-{time.month:02}-{time.day:02}T{time.hour:02}:{time.minute:02}:{time.second:02}.{millisecond:03}{tz}"

    ## handle rounding up to the next second
    if dt.microsecond >= 999500:
        dt -= timedelta(microseconds=dt.microsecond)
        dt += timedelta(seconds=1)

    return fmt.format(time=dt, millisecond=int(round(dt.microsecond/1000.0)), tz=dt.strftime("%z"))
```

For example:

```
In [130]: d1 = datetime(2015,03,15,2,05,59,999999)

In [131]: datetime_to_iso(d1)
Out[131]: '2015-03-15T02:06:00.000'

In [132]: d2 = datetime(2015,03,15,2,05,59,456789)

In [133]: datetime_to_iso(d2)
Out[133]: '2015-03-15T02:05:59.457'
```

Comment: Two interesting points about ISO8601: it allows the tz offset to be printed HH:MM or HHMM or just HH. It also doesn't mandate the number of decimal places in the seconds fraction. That said, I've still had plenty of headaches with 3rd party libs and services not playing nice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer., It's a hack but it will do as long as don't find another

Comment: Ok, I know the [famous adage](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Attributed) was only supposed to apply when using regex to parse html, but I think it's applicable here too.

Comment: Replaced hacky regex based solution with a better one which slightly refines RoadieRich's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The same format that can parse that format:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> ts='2015-05-13T18:05:55.320-0700'
>>> tf="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"
>>> dt=datetime.strptime(ts, tf)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 13, 18, 5, 55, 320000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200)))
```

Can also print it:

```
>>> dt.strftime(tf)
'2015-05-13T18:05:55.320000-0700'
```

Note the lack of the ':' in the tz however.

You can also use isoformat() to print your target:

```
>>> dt.isoformat()
2015-05-13T18:05:55.320000-07:00
```